# Is this Beppo-Levi curl space a Banach space?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces, schwartz-distributions, quotient-space

Let us define the quotient space:

$$ V = \{ \mathbf{u} \in L^2_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^3; \mathbb{R}^3) : \operatorname{curl} \mathbf u \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^3; \mathbb{R}^3) \} / \nabla H^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^3). $$

My question is whether or not this is a Banach space equipped with the norm:

$$\| [\mathbf u] \|_V = \left( \int_{\mathbb R^3} |\operatorname{curl} \mathbf u|^2 \right)^{1/2}. $$

I would proceed as follows: to see that $\| \cdot \|_V$ is actually a norm, notice that $\operatorname{curl} \mathbf u =0$ in $L^2$ implies $\operatorname{curl} \mathbf u = 0$ in $\mathcal{D}'$, whence by the generalized Poincaré lemma (for currents) $\mathbf u = \nabla T \in L^2_{loc}$ for some $T \in \mathcal{D}'$. It follows that $T$ itself is in $L^2_{loc}$ and in conclusion $[\mathbf u] = [0]$.

Now let $([\mathbf u_j])_j$ be a Cauchy sequence, then $(\operatorname{curl} \mathbf u_j)$ is Cauchy in $L^2$ and we find $\mathbf g \in L^2$ such that $\operatorname{curl} \mathbf u_j \rightarrow \mathbf g$ in $L^2$. It remains to prove that $\mathbf g$ is the (distributional) curl of an $L^2_{loc}$ vector field, which is the delicate part. It is rather easy to show that $\operatorname{div} \mathbf g = 0$ in $\mathcal{D}'$ so that $\mathbf g = \operatorname{curl} F$ for some $F \in \mathcal{D}'$, but unfortunately having an $L^2_{loc}$ distributional curl does not guarantee any additional regularity of $F$ itself (in constrast with the gradient case).

Alternatively I would try to extract a sequence $(\mathbf u_j) \subset L^2_{loc}$ from $[\mathbf u_j]$ and show that $\mathbf u_j \rightarrow \mathbf u^{*}$ in $L^2_{loc}$, the conclusion would follow by the uniqueness of the distributional limit. This process is clear for more classical spaces when we have a gradient in place of the curl and the constants in place of the gradients (indeed it suffices for impose zero mean value on a ball...), here I cannot see how to go on, neither I can exhibit a Cauchy sequence which does not convergence.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.